# How do I fix a row in a Gridpane in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I have a GridPane of data the I'm populating in javafx.  The top row is the title cells and I need them to be fixed vertically so they are always on the screen, (such as freezing panes in excel).

I've tried using two scrollpanes.  This did not work so far because I'm trying to hide the scrollbar of the top scrollpane.  I'll need to be able to have the top scrollpane scroll in sync with the x axis of the bottom scrollpane, I just want the scrollbar to be hidden.

I've thought about using a stackpane instead of the above mentioned method but I'm not sure how to hide the horizontal scrollbar.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Here's my FXML

```
    <BorderPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:id="results_pane" >
    <top>
       <ScrollPane fx:id="results_scroll_pane_titles" >
                <GridPane fx:id="results_grid_view_titles">

                </GridPane>
            </ScrollPane> 
    </top>
    <left><VBox fx:id="paint_tools_results"></VBox></left>
    <center>

            <ScrollPane fx:id="results_scroll_pane">
                <GridPane fx:id="results_grid_view">

                </GridPane>
            </ScrollPane>
   </center>
   <right>
       <VBox fx:id="queue_button_tools" alignment="BOTTOM_LEFT" >

           <ScrollPane hbarPolicy="NEVER" fx:id="queue_scrollpane" >
           <VBox fx:id="selected_page_queue">
              <padding><Insets top="0" right="10" bottom="0" left="0"/></padding>
           </VBox>
            </ScrollPane> 
            <HBox>
                <Button prefWidth="105" fx:id="view_all">View</Button>
                <Button prefWidth="105" fx:id="remove_all" >Remove All</Button>
            </HBox>
       </VBox>      
   </right> 
</BorderPane>
```

Also this is the code I tried to use to hide the scrollbar:

```
Set<Node> nodes = results_scroll_pane_titles.lookupAll(".scroll-bar");
            nodes.stream().filter((node) -> (node instanceof ScrollBar)).map((node) -> (ScrollBar) node).forEach((sb) -> {
                if (sb.getOrientation() == Orientation.HORIZONTAL) {
                    title_scrollbar = sb;
                }
                sb.setVisible(false);

            });
```

It found the scrollbar and hid the actual slider bar, but the background bar was still visible.

Comment: hints: height percentage , width percentage in GridPane

Comment: I'm not sure how that applies to this problem.  The Gridpane cells are fixed width and they need to be.

Comment: Wouldn’t a [TableView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html) make this easier?

Comment: I was afraid someone was going to say that.  I probably should have pursued that in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a fix.  While it was pointed out that I could use a tableview by @VGR,  I decided to take a different approach since I was farther along using a gridpane.

The way that I did it was by making the font size of the scroll pane 1px.

```
results_scroll_pane_titles.setStyle("-fx-font-size:1px");
```

This didn't completely remove the scrollbar, but it was great for my needs.  of course I then needed to override the font size for the child elements.

Once I did this I was able to bind the scrollbar to scroll along the h axis of the other scrollbar.

```
hPosition.bind(results_scroll_pane.hvalueProperty());
            hPosition.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue arg0, Object arg1, Object arg2) {
                     results_scroll_pane_titles.setHvalue((double) arg2);

                }
            });
```

I think for my purposes this worked out better than a table view since tableviews have some overhead that I don't need to mess with.